# How to remove password from Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, password-management

I have used autologin.exe, and it worked for removing user password from Windows 8.1, when booting my laptop and waking from sleep, but I want to know if there is a cleaner way to do it, without using any extra tools?

Comment: Password for what exactly you never specify

Comment: User password when booting up

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to enable automatic login in windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/495015/how-to-enable-automatic-login-in-windows-8), http://superuser.com/questions/532299/autologin-a-user-windows-8, http://superuser.com/questions/88263/how-to-enable-autologon-in-windows-7, http://superuser.com/questions/522947/automatically-logging-into-windows-xp/523033#523033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open the Run window by pressing the Windows key + R or launch the Command Prompt. Type one of the following two commands: netplwiz.exe or control userpasswords2. No matter which one you use, they have identical results and launch the same window.

Once you run the command, a User Accounts window similar to the one below will launch. There you will see the list of users registered on your PC.

How to Set a User to Log On Automatically

Select the user for which you no longer want to type the password in order to log in to Windows.

Uncheck the option which says 'Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer' and click or tap OK.

Now you will are asked to type the password of that user twice. When done, click or tap OK.

The next time you will start Windows, you will be automatically logged on with the user you just selected. This user will become the default log on user to Windows 7.

Referral Link : http://www.7tutorials.com/log-automatically-windows-7-without-typing-your-password